# JMeter to use variables as template

Tags: templates, variables, groovy, jmeter

In JMeter, how to define variables as template first then use them later?

I want to sent them out as my request body, but because I cannot get it working now, I'm trying to set my JSR223's response instead:

```
//SampleResult.setResponseData("abc", "UTF-8")

body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"
SampleResult.setResponseData(__evalVar(body), "UTF-8")
//SampleResult.setResponseData(${__evalVar(body)}, "UTF-8")
vars.put("body",body)
//SampleResult.setResponseData(${__evalVar(vars.get("body")}, "UTF-8")
```

So the fist option `//SampleResult.setResponseData("abc", "UTF-8")` is working if uncommented. However, starting from the second `setResponseData`, all my attempts failed.

My ultimate goal is,

- define a template string and put it in with `vars.put`, like the above `vars.put("body",body)`
- then dynamically change the `subject` variable values,
- and finally such template string will be evaluated as `Hello, World!` (as put in my http request body)

**UPDATE Begins:**

What's the minimum version of JMeter to make use of:

```
body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"

SampleResult.setResponseData(body, "UTF-8")
```

I'm using JMeter 5.4.1 but I'm not getting the desired result:

> [image]

(I know JMeter 5.4.1 is not the latest but it is not up to me to decide which version to use)

**UPDATE Ends.**

So,

- How can I do that, and
- What's the best way to debug/proof that my single evaluation function call will work in my http request body, just like I can validation my above with JSR223's response? I've tried to sent them out in `Java Request`, and `jp@gc - Dummy Sampler`, both request and response, but none of them is working for me (getting them as-is without being evaluated instead).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call [__evalVar() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) because:

1. It is designed for evaluating [JMeter Variable expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Your syntax is incorrect
3. In general [it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

So you just need to do something like:

```
body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"

SampleResult.setResponseData(body, "UTF-8")
```

And your JSR223 Sampler's response data will become `Hello, World!`

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! What's the answer to my last question? Say I have defined `body` and `subject` in previous steps, how to use `body` in my http request body, if better not to inline it? And, which controller is best to check it, do I have to send my http request to some fake site (and errors out), or there is better way? thx!

Comment: Moreover, What's the minimum version of JMeter to make use of your answer?
I ***have to*** use JMeter 5.4.1 but I'm not getting the desired result. See updated OP for details.