# How is this JMeter variables as template possible?

Tags: templates, variables, groovy, jmeter

Follow up on the unanswered part of [JMeter to use variables as template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587792/jmeter-to-use-variables-as-template), about

JSR223 Sampler's response data becoming `Hello, World!`:

[image]

```
body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"

SampleResult.setResponseData(body, "UTF-8")
```

I tried it in both JMeter 5.4.1 and JMeter 5.5, but none is working for me:

> [image]

> [image]

How to make it work for *normal* JMeter (both 5.4.1 and 5.5) please?

**UPDATE:**

I've update the code to be:

```
body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"

log.info(body)
SampleResult.setResponseData(body, "UTF-8")
```

Once again, this question is about

> *how to define variables as template first then use them later?*

So the `body` has to be defined before `subject`.

I've put the wholo jmx file at https://pastebin.com/uMApEPxd

I'm running it under
**Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 21H2 Build 19044**
with,

```
C:\>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

C:\>groovy -v
Groovy Version: 3.0.11 JVM: 11.0.2 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
```

[image]

Using the latest JMeter 5.5 freshly downloaded from the official site, and without even having the plugin manager installed:

[image]

I've set the logging to the trace level and put the whole log at
https://pastebin.com/gTnCm5w2

Comment: `${}` syntax is both in groovy and JMeter and thefore will create issues/confusion, why you need it?

Comment: I don't need it @user7294900, as long as there is a way for JMeter to use variables as template, I'm happy.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786399/jmeter-groovy-script-concatenation-of-variables

Comment: Sorry @user7294900, I checked your link but I'm too new to JMeter and Groovy to make sense out of it so as to apply to my case -- to use variables as template for JMeter. Seems to be totally different questions to me.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been fully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73590963/2897748).

If it doesn't work for **your** JMeter then probably your installation got corrupt somehow, [re-install JMeter from scratch](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation), don't add any plugins and try the code exactly copied and pasted from the below box:

```
subject = "World"
body = "Hello, ${subject}!"
SampleResult.setResponseData(body, "UTF-8")
```

If you still experience problems - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). If there is no information there - enable debug logging for the JSR223 test elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my updated OP.

Comment: I'm not going to check your "updated OP" (whatever it means), given you use my code you will get the expected behaviour. Just [learn a little bit of Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/learn.html)